# Saving multi-level entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, circular-reference

I have a 3 level entity and I am having some trouble saving it.

```
public partial class Event
{
    public Event()
    {
        Recurrences = new HashSet<Recurrence>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Recurrence> Recurrences { get; set; }
}

public partial class Recurrence
{
    public Recurrence()
    {
        AspNetUsers = new HashSet<AspNetUser>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public string Venue { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AspNetUser> AspNetUsers { get; set; }
}

public partial class AspNetUser
{
    public AspNetUser()
    {
        Recurrences = new HashSet<Recurrence>();
    }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Recurrence> Recurrences { get; set; }
}
```

The Post controller for the Event Class looks like this:

```
// POST: api/Events
[ResponseType(typeof(Event))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostEvent(EventDTO @event)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

        var newEvent = new Event();
        newEvent.Title = @event.Title;
        newEvent.EventTypeId = @event.EventTypeId;

        var recurrence = new Recurrence();
        recurrence.Venue = @event.Venue;

        var users = db.AspNetUsers.Where(u => @event.UserId.Contains(u.Id));
        foreach (var u in users)
            recurrence.AspNetUsers.Add(u);

        newEvent.Recurrences.Add(recurrence);

        db.Events.Add(newEvent);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = newEvent.Id }, newEvent);
    }
```

When I call the PostEvent method with an Event like DTO i get the http error code 500.

first, how can i add exception handling to capture the specific error and secondly, what I'm I doing wrong here?

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You should be getting more than just a 500. What exception is thrown? Do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: I am calling the method from a iPhone application. The error message also say, "The operation couldn't be completed {$id=1, Message=An error has occurred.}

Comment: do you own the controller? Can you call it from the server where it is running? That should give you a more detailed error message.

Comment: yes, I own the controller. I am not sure how to debug it while its running without writing a mvc page (which I'm not familiar with) to supply the data to add. That is why i would like to add error handling to maybe detect exactly where its happening and maybe a specify error description.

Comment: try this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb684665.aspx